# Concat files in Apache ANT to variable?

Tags: ant, build

I know that I can use ANT's `concat` to merge several files into one file. But what about merging files into a variable?

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`concat`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) can be used as a resource collection, so you can use it in a [`loadresource`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html):

```
<loadresource property="the.property">
  <concat>
    <file file="foo.txt" />
    <file file="another_file.txt />
    <string>You can put any resource in here, not just files!</string>
  </concat>
</loadresource>
```

Now the `the.property` property will contain the concatenation of all the resources inside the `concat`. (I'm assuming you mean an ant property when you say variable.)

Comment: That's great. Completely missed that! Thanks a lot